# using map() in R purrr

Tags: r, apply, tidyverse, purrr

I'm learning to use the map() family of functions in purrr and don't understand why the following works...

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(5,4,3), col2=c("a", "b", "c"))

my_f <- function(v1){
      output <- v1 + 1
      return(output)
    }

addone_v <- df$col1 %>%
  map_dbl(my_f)
```

but not if change `map_dbl()` to `map()`. In the latter case I get the error:

```
Error in paste("(^", regions, ")", sep = "", collapse = "|") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

which is an error message I don't understand.

I thought map() was the safest to use when I'm uncertain of the type of output I might get.

Comment: Are you running exactly what you showed? As written, I don't get the error you supplied. Perhaps you are not assigning the result to `addone_v`, but to a column of a data.frame?

Comment: Not clear about the error.  What is `regions`  etc.

Comment: Are you saying `df$col1 %>% map(my_f)` returns the error message you pasted into your question?  I also can't reproduce.

Comment: I messed up with the namespaces. works when using purrr::map()

Comment: This is a better syntax tho: ```{df$col1} %>%
  map(my_f)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are updating the same column, apply the function within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
      mutate(col1 = map_dbl(col1, my_f))
```

NOTE: Here, it may not require any loop (`map`) though

---

If we are applying the function on `map`, the default output is a `list`

```
df$col1 %>% 
   map(my_f)
#[[1]]
#[1] 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 4
```

Comment: it seems i had a namespace issue. I can get your results when i try purrr::map()

Comment: @val May be your `ls()` may have object identifiers as `map` or have the same function name from different package eg. from `maps`

Comment: that's right - i had loaded the `maps` package after `tidyverse`. thank you